# Creating a list or array with a fixed size?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create an array or list which only contains 3 entries at any given time. The function should loop and with each loop 1 entry will be added to the list pushing the oldest value out and then a value will be calculated based on the 3 values in the list.

I have tried:

```
import numpy as np

z = np.ndarray((3,),float)

np.append(z, [12, 14.56, 12.46, 1.56])
```

which creates a numpy array with only 3 values (afaik) however the array is populated with strange values:

```
z= ([  1.56889217e-163,   1.01899555e-297,   1.03395110e-297])
```

anyone know why/what I'm doing wrong or have a better solution for what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z` is being initialized as an empty array.  Those strange values are just random numbers that were in the empty memory slots before `z` was created.  You need to have an initial value.

Start with:

```
z = np.array([14.56, 12.46, 1.56])
```

And then modify its values, but don't `append` (that changes the size of the array).

Then here's an example of a function that will 'roll' the elements of your array back by one (or any number) and then replace the first value with a new value.

```
def push(a, n):
     a = np.roll(a, 1)
     a[0] = n
     return a
```

Of course, instead of `n`, you want to use your function of `a`.  For example, if you want to append the sum of the original array to the beginning:

```
def push_sum(a):
     a = np.roll(a, 1)
     a[0] = a.sum()
     return a
```

Then:

```
In [19]: z = np.array([14.56, 12.46, 1.56])

In [20]: push(z, 14)
Out[20]: array([ 14.  ,  14.56,  12.46])

In [29]: push_sum(z)
Out[29]: array([ 28.58,  14.56,  12.46])
```

Comment: way does the output have more than 3 items?

Comment: It does indeed, that was mainly because I was trying to find out which value it would drop in that case, but this answers my question anyway

Comment: @mark Trying to assign `N` values to an array of `length ≠ N` will just give you a `ValueError`

Answer (score 5):

Use a `deque`:

```
from collections import deque
z = deque(maxlen=3)
z.extend([1, 2, 3, 4])
print z
# deque([2, 3, 4], maxlen=3)
z.append(5)
# deque([3, 4, 5], maxlen=3)
print z
```

You can also `appendleft` and `extendleft` on a deque if you need to.